# Create a real time GPS tracking system

Tags: javascript, gps, maps

I am creating a GPS tracking system. I am able to collect the real time coordinates. Now I want to move the marker in real time in the web interface using Google Maps V3. What I know is to move the marker if I know the starting & ending point. But here since the system is live the ending point will keep on changing dynamically. I cannot refresh the page.You can find [coordinate logging here](http://krititech.com/check/check1.php)

Answer (score 1):

Its very simple - just use the [setPosition](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html) method ... example :

```
var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng( 50, 50 ); // initial position
var marker = new google.maps.Marker( {position: myLatLng, map: map} ); // add to map
marker.setPosition( new google.maps.LatLng( 52, 52 ) ); // move it
```

[Simple demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/veEVg/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Good structure but not actual. i think the new variable is not declare value of it, even googlemap try to find it. when i run this in my device and edit too still show wrong location. i hope we may find new idea to locate. 
for this, i think any other method will be more effective than "new", because syntax.